Laravel : I want to rate limit API so only one session per IP address should access the application
Problem statement:- We are running a laravel application and receiving requests from worldwide. We want to rate limit API so only one session per IP address should access the application. Another session request should show a prompt for previous sessions in progress and does not allow new sessions.
A button to continue the second session and close the previous session, the previous session on the browser window should be closed.
In Laravel Code How can i do this so one session per IP address using rate limit.

Are you sure you want to do that? You realize that this will prevent access if two people access from the same network, right?

Yes i know, i want to do it. Can You help me on this. How Can i do this

what does rate limit have to do with this?

One approach is to use a middleware for the specific routes your users will be calling
However, others have warned you need to be careful of a client that spoofs IP or shared IP scenarios (like users behind a NAT) as this could prevent some users from accessing the application simultaneously from the same network.
if you are still interested in achieving this you can create a middleware :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class LimitOneSessionPerIP
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request                                       $request
     * @param Closure(Request): (Response|RedirectResponse) $next
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $ip = $request->ip();
        $sessionId = session()->getId();

        $existingSessionId = Cache::get('ip_sessions:' . $ip);

        if ($existingSessionId && $existingSessionId !== $sessionId) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Another session is already active from this IP address. Close the previous session to continue.',
            ], 429);
        }
        
        Cache::put('ip_sessions:' . $ip, $sessionId, now()->addMinutes(30)); // Adjust timing as necessary

        return $next($request);
    }
}



register the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php so it can be applied to routes.
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // add to existing middleware
    'limit.ip.session' => \App\Http\Middleware\LimitOneSessionPerIP::class,
];


apply to route
Route::middleware(['limit.ip.session'])->group(function () {
  
});


or
you can customize the laravels ratelimiter for this
in your AppServiceProvider
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

public function boot()
{
    RateLimiter::for('custom', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}



and then
Route::middleware('throttle:custom')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        
    });
});


or if you are looking for something more sophisticated, use a rate-limiting php/laravel package. they tend to do an awesome job.
